# xaml: multiple selected items in datagrid, each datagrid has a combobox, selecteditem changes every combobox - should only change selected combobox

Tags: list, xaml, mvvm, datagrid, combobox

I have a datagrid like so:

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems, Mode=OneWay}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

in each item of the datagrid I have a combobox with a list of items:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.SubItems}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboItem}"
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

unfortunately, whenever I change 1 combobox, all other comboboxes also change their selected item.

Help ! I've looking for a solution for an entire day now...

Comment: This is normal, you bind the same property to all your comboboxes, so when that property (SelectedComboItem) changes, it will reflect to all your comboboxes.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is not binding it and doing it all programmatically... any other solutions please?

Comment: You don't have to do it all programmatically. You can use the selecteditemchanged event on the combobox and the the value in the codebehind, this way, you'll use most of you current solution, just changing where it goes wrong.

Comment: that will solve changing the value in the combobox (not persisting it to other comboboxes)..... but I'll have to do more than that unfortunately, because whenever I change the selecteditem in the datagrid, all comboboxes get a different selecteditem (since when I select a new datagrid-item the combobox of that datagrid-item has a default selected-combobox-item)

Comment: Since I'm in a bit of a rush to finish this, I'm going to just skip the binding and program it and use the selectionchanged event..... I feel like I'm commiting a crime of some sort... :-)

Comment: You are binding your datagrid `ItemSource` to `MyItems`, so why aren't your combobox bindings then in the context of those items? If the comboboxes are within the datagrid their binding should be to the row item they represent. Show more code.
From the snippets you've shown I would expect `MyItems` to have a property called `SelectedComboItem`, and also a `SelectedItem.SubItems` (which probably isn't what you want). The `ItemsSource` on the combos should probably come from the ViewModel, but the `SelectedItem should be coming from the item they refer to in the containing DataGrid `ItemSource`.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but I have no idea on how to write this...  all objects are also represented in the viewmodel:

    MyItems  (each MyItem has SubItems),
    SelectedItem,
    SelectedItem.SubItems,
    SelectedComboItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example from something in use here, I've chopped out everything apart from the combobox within a datagrid so hopefully you can see where you've gone wrong with your bindings/logic:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="MyDatagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Combo column"  IsReadOnly="False">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboItem,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Things to note:
`MyItems` is a ViewModel property
`SubItems` is a property of class of items within MyItems, not the ViewModel. If you want your combobox ItemSource to come from the viewmodel then you will need something like:

```
{Binding DataContext.AllComboItems,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid}, Mode=OneWay}
```

`SelectedComboItem` is also a property on the class of items within MyItems, not the ViewModel.